# Flutter CheckBox issue

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Checkbox on my page which is false initially, but when I mark it true nad I pop from the page and when I go back to the Checkbox page again the Checkbox is false instead of true, it should be true as I have already ticked it off.

here is my code:

```
class _BookWidgetState extends State<BookWidget> {
   bool checkBoxValue = false;


   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     final length = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
     return Card(
       color: Theme.of(context).buttonColor,
       elevation: 5,
       child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    children: <Widget>[
      SizedBox(
          width: length.width * 0.15,
          child: Checkbox(
              value: checkBoxValue,
              onChanged: (bool value) {
                setState(() {
                  checkBoxValue = value;
                });
              })),
      Container(
        width: length.width * 0.50,
        child: Text(
          widget.items.title,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 15,
            color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.arrow_forward,
          color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
        ),
        onPressed: widget.onTap,
      ),
      SizedBox(
        width: length.width * 0.01,
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
}
}
```

---

```
 onTap: () => NextScreen.show(
            context,
            database: Provider.of<Database>(context),
            items: items,
          ),
```

Comment: can you add the code for `widget.onTap` function from the arrow icon?

Comment: That takes to the next page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you pop from the page, the widget is removed from the widget tree and discarded. When you return to the page, the widget is rebuilt and inserted into the widget tree. It will be rebuilt fresh, exactly the way you coded it, including setting `checkBoxValue` to false.

What you need to do is save the `checkBoxValue` and load it from memory. This isn't done automatically, you need to do it yourself. You can do this using the [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) plugin.

```
class _BookWidgetState extends State<BookWidget> {
  bool checkBoxValue = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadCheckBox(); // Load the save when StatefulWidget is first created
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final length = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Card(
      color: Theme.of(context).buttonColor,
      elevation: 5,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
              width: length.width * 0.15,
              child: Checkbox(
                  value: checkBoxValue,
                  onChanged: (bool value) {
                    setState(() {
                      checkBoxValue = value;
                      saveCheckBox(); // Save when value is changed
                    });
                  })),
          Container(
            width: length.width * 0.50,
            child: Text(
              widget.items.title,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 15,
                color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.arrow_forward,
              color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
            ),
            onPressed: widget.onTap,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: length.width * 0.01,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  saveCheckBox() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setBool('checkBoxValue', checkBoxValue);
  }

  loadCheckBox() async {
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      bool savedValue = prefs.getBool('checkBoxValue');
      setState(() {
         checkBoxValue = savedValue?? false; // Set checkBoxValue to savedValue. The null-aware operator ensures that if savedValue is null, checkBoxValue is set to false
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the error seems to be in the Boolean type variable "value",
Or rather in the setState() part. Check up on the code under Statefulwidget.That might solve your problem.

Comment: I am under StatefulWidget, still every time I pop off from the page and reenter the page the Checkbox will be false even if I change it to true. So should I not set the initial value to false?

Comment: try creating a  method under the _BookWidgetstate class with the code of set state and then link it to the checkbox.